# Plugin Guidelines require plugin to be GNU General Public License

Tags: plugins

So I have a freemium plugin I want to upload to the WordPress plugin store. My plugin is free to use and you can purchase addon features (so theres only 1 plugin you just unlock features).

According to WP guidelines, the plugin must use the license GNU General Public License. Doesn't that license contradict the freemium sales model or not? Can I distribute the plugin under the GNU General Public License and not violate it by being freemium?

Or do I have to distribute my plugin through another means, like envato or something, because my plugin is freemium?

Comment: You pay for the distribution, eitherway if it's not GPL compatible it would violate the WP license, regardless of where you host it. You're best checking the WP Plugin guidelines, there are restrictions around these things, the .org forums might be a better place to ask about plugin policy

Comment: Freemius can make free version fully compatible to .org requirements.